# pandas dataframe rolling window with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can add a new column `c` that is a sum of the last two values in `b` as shown below...

```
df['c'] = df.b.rolling(window = 2).sum().shift()

df
    a   b     c
0   1   3   NaN
1   1   0   NaN
2   0   6   3.0
3   1   0   6.0
4   0   0   6.0
5   1   7   0.0
6   0   0   7.0
7   0   7   7.0
8   1   4   7.0
9   1   2   11.0
```

...however, what if I want to group by `a` first? E.g. I can do this:

`df['c'] = df.groupby(['a'])['b'].shift(1) + df.groupby(['a'])['b'].shift(2)`

Is there a more elegant way for summing a large number of shifts (1, 2, ...n) on a group?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
f = lambda x: x.rolling(2).sum().shift()
df['c'] = df.groupby('a').b.apply(f)

df
```

[image]

Comment: caution: combining the rolling() and shift() methods in a lambda function (just the way piRSquared presented it) is necessary: it causes *both* to be applied to the group (desirable); 

incorrect behavior occurs in this case: `df['c'] = df.groupby('a').b.rolling(2).sum().shift()` since the shift() operation occurs in a non-grouped context

Comment: Sorry, I hope I didn't add confusion: I meant to say that *your approach is correct* and that an alternate approach, which may seem to be a syntactic preference, will lead to unintended behavior