# Issue with groupby and rolling window

Tags: python, pandas

Related to: [pandas dataframe rolling window with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701317/pandas-dataframe-rolling-window-with-groupby)

I have some `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1], 
              'rank':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,1,2,3,4], 
              'score':[5,8,10,12,4,9,13,23,42,4,9,10,8,12,48,9]})
```

I'd like to add a new column that includes the rolling average of the `scores` for each `type` for every 4 `ranks`.

Something like this is pretty close to what I want:

```
f = lambda x: x.rolling(4, min_periods=4).mean()
df['rolling'] = df.groupby('type')['score'].apply(f)
```

But I want to start averaging from the first `rank` in each `type`. The last 3 `ranks` should return NaN, e.g.:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to `mean` if need shift per groups:

```
f = lambda x: x.rolling(4, min_periods=4).mean().shift(-3)
df['rolling'] = df.groupby('type')['score'].apply(f)
```

What should be same if add `shift` of all values outside groups, I hope:

```
df['rolling'] = (df.groupby('type')
                   .score.rolling(4, min_periods=4)
                   .mean()
                   .shift(-3)
                   .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

---

```
print (df)
    type  rank  score  rolling
0      0     0      5     8.75
1      0     1      8     8.50
2      0     2     10     8.75
3      0     3     12     9.50
4      0     4      4    12.25
5      0     5      9    21.75
6      0     6     13    20.50
7      0     7     23    19.50
8      0     8     42      NaN
9      0     9      4      NaN
10     0    10      9      NaN
11     1     0     10    19.50
12     1     1      8    19.25
13     1     2     12      NaN
14     1     3     48      NaN
15     1     4      9      NaN
```